# DateTime index produces wrong x axis labels

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have the following dataframe that contains the following datetime index

```py
DatetimeIndex(['2020-08-08 14:16:51', '2020-08-08 14:16:56',
               '2020-08-08 14:17:01', '2020-08-08 14:17:06',
               '2020-08-08 14:17:11', '2020-08-08 14:17:16',
               '2020-08-08 14:17:21', '2020-08-08 14:17:26',
               '2020-08-08 14:17:31', '2020-08-08 14:17:36',
               '2020-08-08 14:17:41', '2020-08-08 14:17:46',
               '2020-08-08 14:17:51', '2020-08-08 14:17:56',
               '2020-08-08 14:18:01', '2020-08-08 14:18:06',
               '2020-08-08 14:18:11', '2020-08-08 14:18:16',
               '2020-08-08 14:18:21', '2020-08-08 14:18:26',
               '2020-08-08 14:18:31', '2020-08-08 14:18:36',
               '2020-08-08 14:18:41', '2020-08-08 14:18:46',
               '2020-08-08 14:18:51', '2020-08-08 14:18:56',
               '2020-08-08 14:19:02', '2020-08-08 14:19:07',
               '2020-08-08 14:19:12', '2020-08-08 14:19:18',
               '2020-08-08 14:19:23', '2020-08-08 14:19:28',
               '2020-08-08 14:19:33', '2020-08-08 14:19:38',
               '2020-08-08 14:19:43', '2020-08-08 14:19:48',
               '2020-08-08 14:19:53', '2020-08-08 14:19:59',
               '2020-08-08 14:20:04', '2020-08-08 14:20:09',
               '2020-08-08 14:20:14', '2020-08-08 14:20:19',
               '2020-08-08 14:20:24', '2020-08-08 14:20:29',
               '2020-08-08 14:20:35', '2020-08-08 14:20:40',
               '2020-08-08 14:20:45', '2020-08-08 14:20:50',
               '2020-08-08 14:20:55', '2020-08-08 14:21:00',
               '2020-08-08 14:21:05', '2020-08-08 14:21:10',
               '2020-08-08 14:21:15', '2020-08-08 14:21:20',
               '2020-08-08 14:21:25', '2020-08-08 14:21:30',
               '2020-08-08 14:21:35'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='ts', freq=None)
```

I want to plot the time series but when I do, I get some really different ticks in the x axis

```py
dataframe.plot.line()
```

with the line chart produced being the following:

[image]

You can see that x axis has values that do not correspond to the index values. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to format x axis to show ticks every 30 seconds and format datetime as `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax = df.plot()
# set monthly locator
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.SecondLocator(interval=30))
# set formatter
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

example plot:

[image]

Of course Y values are different in my chart.